# Exporting enum in `.d.ts` leads to „Can't resolve” error

Tags: typescript

yesterday I was adding an `enum` to our `app.d.ts` file, which holds most of the global app-specific types.

The file looks roughly like this:

```js
// app.d.ts
export module App
{
    // … more definitions

    enum MyEnum
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }
}
```

Which in itself is compiling fine. Now, if you try to use said enum in a different file like this:

```js
// a.ts
import {App} from "./app";

let something = App.MyEnum.A;
```

TypeScript is complaining that it suddenly can't resolve the file `app.d.ts`.

[image: TypeScript compile error]

After a lot of debugging and reading through the docs, I found the [following disclaimer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime):

> Enums are real objects that exist at runtime

So when moving `MyEnum` from `app.d.ts` to its own `MyEnum.ts` file and explicitly exporting it, it suddenly works:

```js
// MyEnum.ts
export enum MyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}
```

- 

```js
// a.ts
import {MyEnum} from "./MyEnum";

let something = MyEnum.A;
```

So now my real question is: Is this due to the fact that TypeScript doesn't inline enum values into constants (unless you're using `const enum`) but keeps them around as real objects, and since the `.d.ts` files are basically thrown away when compiling TypeScript into JavaScript, it fails with this very weird and sort of unrelated error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I just had the very same error and your question here helped me fix it right away (thanks!), I assume that the answer to your question would be: Yes, exporting/importing `enum`s from `.d.ts` files does not work and causes this somewhat misleading error.

What works though, is putting a `.ts` file with the same name in the same place, so that in your case for example `app.d.ts` and `app.ts` co-exist in the same folder. This lets you import the `enum` without having to change the import. Import still works with `import { MyEnum } from "./app";` in your case.